# Asterisk Manager API - Extension -> ZAP Channel

Tags: api, asterisk

Is there a way to retrieve the ZAP channel from an extension number through the Manager API?

For example, this is what I see when I run "zap show channels":

```
   Chan Extension  Context         Language   MOH Interpret
```

...

```
     33 3594       from-zaptel     en         default
```

...

But Manager API only returns the following (without extension):

```
Event: ZapShowChannels 
Channel: 33
Signalling: FXS Kewlstart 
Context: from-zaptel
DND: Disabled 
Alarm: No Alarm 
ActionID: aci-1234
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which version of asterisk you are working with. I assume asterisk 1.2 because in newer versions "zaptel" has been renamed to "dahdi".

It's a bit of a work around, but you can request the missing information for each channel with the "GetVar" Action.

*send:*

```
Action: GetVar
Channel: Zap/33
Variable: EXTEN
```

*receive:*

```
Response: Success
EXTEN: 3594
```